# Add row and column at zero position in matrix Eigen

Tags: vector, matrix, eigen

I've got the matrix for example : C(400,400)

and I would like to grow this matrix with one vector: row and column of this matrix at the begin-index 0 of the matrix for example :

Matrix C:

```
 3 2 5 
 4 5 6
 7 8 20
```

my new vector :  25 5 6 8

Result :

```
  25 5 6 8
  5  3 2 5 
  6  4 5 6
  8  7 8 20
```

Whats the best way in Eigen to do this? Use `.resize()`, and `.set`? Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

The best I can come up with is:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd newC(C.rows()+1, C.cols()+1);
newC << v.transpose(), v.tail(v.size()-1), C;
C.swap(newC);
```

This assumes your "new vector" is stored as a column vector in `v`. The variable `newC` is no longer needed after this fragment.

Answer (score 3):

Though I would use Jitse's method as well, to give you another choice, here is a solution that is a bit more verbose and may show better where the parts go:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd newC(C.rows()+1, C.cols()+1);
newC.topRows<1>() = v.transpose();
newC.leftCols<1>() = v;
newC.bottomRightCorner(C.rows(),C.cols()) = C;
C.swap(newC)
```

Note that this assigns the top left element twice; if you don't want that, replace the third line with this ugly one:

```
newC.topRows<1>().tail(v.size()-1) = v.transpose().tail(v.size()-1);
```

As a final note as to why we don't use `resize`: it always throws away your matrix content (even when shrinking a matrix), except when the number of elements stays exactly the same, i.e. when you resize an `MxN` matrix to size `(M*k)x(N/k)`.